# .htaccess image path how to create

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My problem is image not showing while writing in .htaccess for RewriteRule. In the image path `details1/cus_id` comes before image path. 
Plz help.

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^details1/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) details1.php?cus_id=$1&ad_id=$2

RewriteRule ^images\/(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))?$ local/root/nfs/ad/data/img/$1/$2/$3 [QSA,L]
```

This is the real image path:

```
http://localhost/root/nfs/ad/data/img/$cus_id/$ad_id/$img_name
```

I made Dynamic Bootstrap Carousel with PHP.

Comment: what's your request uri and what is the expected image path?

Comment: `root/nfs` is worrying, you should mount the directory so apache user can access it, (in webroot). Then its just normal path to the file relative to your webroot.

Comment: `$1/$2/$3` means "the first match, the second match, the third match" so your regex makes no sense as it only has max 2 matches (the filename as well as the extension - `(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^details1/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) details1.php?cus_id=$1&ad_id=$2

RewriteRule ^ad/data/img/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|ico|jpg) ad/data/img/$1/$2/$3
```